# Automaticaly start JavaScript function when page loads

Tags: javascript, function

Have some problem with my JavaScript code which you can see below.

So, the code counts characters in some textarea and counts it in real time, when user is typing something. Depending on symbols count user have two infromations:

1. Some text message depended on count
2. Number of characters

The problem is, that code starts just when we type at least one symbol. But in my website I have in this textarea some information which loads from database, when page loads, so the textarea already have some symbols. But the count function doesn't starts when page load, as I said, we need to type (or delete) at least one symbol.

I know, that thought my code is should works so, because I use **onkeyup** event.
But, I also tried to use **onload** Event.
Also tried to add `window.onload = countDescriptionChar(this)`; to Script code

But it still doesn't work.

So, I need to start the script when page loaded (when we don't have any key pressed) and save the functionality to count characters in real time when the user press some key.

I think I do something wrong...

You have all my code below

Thanks for help!

**Here is the JavaScript code I use for it**

```
        function countDescriptionChar(val) {
            var len = val.value.length;
            if ((len >= 0) && (len < 105)) {
                $('#symbolsDescription').text(len);
                document.getElementById("statusDescription").innerHTML = "<span style='color: orangered'>less then 105 characters</span>";
            }
            else if ((len >= 105) && (len <= 135)) {
                $('#symbolsDescription').text(len);
                document.getElementById("statusDescription").innerHTML = "<span style='color: green'>Idealy! (105 - 135 characters)</span>";
            }
            else {
                $('#symbolsDescription').text(len);
                document.getElementById("statusDescription").innerHTML = "<span style='color: orangered'>Too much... (more then 135)</span>";
            }
        };
```

**Then my HTML code which I use in template.**
I use Laravel to show data in textarea from database

```
<label for="" class="mt-4">Description</label>
<div id="statusDescription"></div>
Symbols: <div class="seocount" id="symbolsDescription"></div>

<textarea class="form-control" id="meta_description" name="meta_description" onkeyup="countDescriptionChar(this)" >
@isset ($article->meta_description)
{{ $article->meta_description}}
@endisset
</textarea>
```

Comment: `window.onload = countDescriptionChar(this)` <--- you're passing `this`, which is not the textarea. Also, I would advise to use `addEventListener` instead of `onload`. Because `onload` will overwrite any previous listener (if other scripts listen for `onload` in the page), resulting in the previous ones not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I added two things that seem to do what you are hoping for:

- Add `$(document).ready(countDescriptionChar())` to your JS code;
- Add a ternary operator that will look for your parameter when you assign the `len` var, if it comes back as "undefined" then it should look for the id of your `<textarea>` and collect it's value

  var len = val === undefined ? document.getElementById('meta_description').value.length : val.value.length

```js
$(document).ready(countDescriptionChar())

function countDescriptionChar(val) {
  
  var len = val === undefined ? 
      document.getElementById('meta_description').value.length :
  val.value.length
  
  if ((len >= 0) && (len < 105)) {
    $('#symbolsDescription').text(len);
    document.getElementById("statusDescription").innerHTML = "<span style='color: orangered'>less then 105 characters</span>";
  }
  else if ((len >= 105) && (len <= 135)) {
    $('#symbolsDescription').text(len);
    document.getElementById("statusDescription").innerHTML = "<span style='color: green'>Idealy! (105 - 135 characters)</span>";
  }
  else {
    $('#symbolsDescription').text(len);
    document.getElementById("statusDescription").innerHTML = "<span style='color: orangered'>Too much... (more then 135)</span>";
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="" class="mt-4">Description</label>
<div id="statusDescription"></div>
Symbols: <div class="seocount" id="symbolsDescription"></div>

<textarea class="form-control" id="meta_description" name="meta_description" onkeyup="countDescriptionChar(this)" >
@isset ($article->meta_description)
{{ $article->meta_description}}
@endisset
</textarea>
```